# Approval Workflow "Approve in Absence of" or "Sign for" option

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval-process

We are looking into the approval workflows, and trying to replicate SharePoint 2013 approval workflows based on existing functionality another vendor's tool supplies.

This other vendor tool allows the setup of "proxy" signers, which means if a manager is out of the office, sick, or is not responding in a timely manner...the proxy signer can sign in place of the manager.

Is there a similar option to almost "Sign as this manger" in the approval workflow or via the SharePoint user account in some manner?  Our goal is to allow admins that may support a manager to sign for the manager if need be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is to use groups in place of individuals.  Each group will have 2 or 3 people in it. When the manager is out one of the others can either approve the item for them or reassign as directed by the Manager.

It's a simple way to keep the workflow process going without having to add additional steps to the overall workflow.